# user.Roles.FirstOrDefault() returns DynamicProxy

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, asp.net-identity

OK...
I was finally making some headway with creating a User Management page using Identity 2 in Web Forms.

It was mostly moving along just fine. When suddenly I run into this issue, and it makes no sense to me.

I have an AS form with a dropdown list of Roles. That list is populated using
roleMgr.Roles.ToList();
Works Great

I use the user being edited Role to set the current selected value.
ddlUserType.SelectedValue = user.Roles.FirstOrDefault().ToString();

This WAS working like dynamite
Last week...
Now all of a sudden user.Roles.FirstOrDefault().ToString(); is returning 
"System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.IdentityUserRole_FDDE5D267CF62D86904A3BC925D70DC410F12D5BE8313308EC89AC8537DC6375"

What he heck, man?

So I tried user.Roles.Take(1).ToString();
That returns 
"System.Linq.Enumerable+d__24`1[Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole]"

I have to presume I Broke, Something...
But What?
Nothing in this code page changed at all between when it worked and then didn't.

The only thing I did related to Identity at all was Migrate a couple of fields into AspNetUsers (another whole ballgame, migrations...) which also worked like dynamite BTW.

I even went to the extreme of wiping out my Migrations and AspNet user tables entirely, and re-initializing it all.

Any suggestions ?

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Sperry_Parts.Models;
using Sperry_Parts.Logic;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Owin;

namespace Parts.Admin
{
    public partial class CreateEditUser : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private bool NewUser
        {
            get { return ViewState["NewUser"] != null ? (bool)ViewState["NewUser"] : false; }
            set { ViewState["NewUser"] = value; } 
        }
        private string EditUser
        {
            get { return (string)ViewState["EditUser"]; }
            set { ViewState["EditUser"] = value; } 
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                EditUser = Session["Edit_User"].ToString();

                // Access the application context and create result variables.
                Models.ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
                RoleActions roleAction = new RoleActions();

                // Create a RoleStore object by using the ApplicationDbContext object. 
                var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);

                // Create a RoleManager object that is only allowed to contain IdentityRole objects.
                var roleMgr = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);

                // Load the DDL of Roles
                var roles = roleMgr.Roles.ToList();
                ddlUserType.DataTextField = "Name";
                ddlUserType.DataValueField = "Id";
                ddlUserType.DataSource = roles;
                ddlUserType.DataBind();

                if (EditUser == "")
                {
                    txtUserName.Enabled = true;
                    txtUserName.Focus();
                    NewUser = true;
                } // End New User
                else 
                {
                    // User part
                    var userMgr = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
                    var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();

                    txtUserName.Enabled = false;
                    txtFullName.Focus();
                    var user = userMgr.FindByName(EditUser);
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        txtUserName.Text = user.UserName;
                        txtUserEmail.Text = user.Email;
                        txtFullName.Text = user.FullName;
                        var hisroles = user.Roles.ToList(); // properly returns 1 item
            // this is where it went off the rails - these 4 lines are debugging code 
                        string xrole = user.Roles.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
                        string role2 = user.Roles.Take(1).ToString();
                        string trythis = xrole.ToString();
                        string trythis2 = role2.ToString();
            // I swear, this worked last week...
                        ddlUserType.SelectedValue = user.Roles.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
                    }
                } // End Editing User
            } // End if (!IsPostBack)
        } // End Page Load

        protected void CreateUser()
        {
        // removed as non-relevant to question
        } // End CreateUser

        protected void UpdateUser()
        {
        // removed as non-relevant to question
        } // End UpdateUser

        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        // removed as non-relevant to question
        } // End btnSave

        protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/ManageUsers");

        } // End btnCancel

    } // End Class CreateEditUser
}
```

Comment: No clues? Anybody?

Comment: I've been hunting all over the place for what could be the problem. Nothing so far relating to the Proxy issue has been a help. I'm really sure that the Roles.FirstOrDefault() Was returning the role Name. I have tried fiddling with  Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled, Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled, nothing seems to have an impact. I thought I found a sample that would Translate the Proxy back, but I think it was written for MVC, and I just can't figure out how to use it. Since I'm only assigning one role per user, for now I just do a lookup. Sloppy but it works. Edit needs >5 minutes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem trying to set the value of a "Roles" DropDownList inside a GridView Control.  I solved it by using:

```
user.Roles.First().RoleId
```

It just happens that my RoleId is also my role name.